# github invite non-github users to private repo

Tags: github

I am setting up a private repository in GitHub and I want to invite people to my repo.

I found out that I can invite github users as my team members, but I want to know is it possible to invite non-github users to access my repo for checkin/checkout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would they authenticate?

Comment: Use ssh keys for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add their ssh keys as [Deployment Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys).

Deployment keys are ssh keys of users (usually, scripts) that are allowed to read the repository so they can build the code and deploy it somewhere.

This would allow your non-githubber coworkers to clone the repository.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an equivalent system to allowing non-githubber to use the web interface.

Comment: Beware: deployment keys grant WRITE access, too!

Comment: It has been five years since this question was asked, is this still the situation with adding non-github users?